# Average and Instantaneous Acceleration

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, acceleration, velocity

This example comes in my Physics book, but I don’t understand one part of the equation.

The velocity of a particle moving along the $x$ axis varies according to the expression $Vx = 40 - 5t^2$, where $Vx$ is in meters per second and $t$ is in seconds.

When finding for Vxf  as in the picture... Why do they substitute time for **(t + Δ(T))**

[image: Principles of Physics: A Calculus Based Approach]

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SE. Your question is such that **its answer does not help other people**. To start with, you use a picture which can not be searched by a search engine. Please come up with a conceptual question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your textbook is taking the time derivative using the limit definition, instead of the power rule shortcut we'd usually take.

Recall that the instantaneous acceleration is$$a(t)=\lim_{\Delta t\to 0} \dfrac{\Delta v}{\Delta t}=\lim_{\Delta t\to 0} \dfrac{v(t+\Delta t)-v(t)}{\Delta t}$$

When calculating $v(t+\Delta t)$, it's simply to plug into the above equation and get the derivative.